# Laravel authorizeResource "This action is unauthorized."

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I have a model called BusinessClient in the namespace `App/BaseData`. For this model I've created a Policy with the command `php artisan make:policy BaseData/BusinessClientPolicy --model=BusinessClient` and registerd it in th e `AuthServiceProvider.php` file.

```
protected $policies = [
    // Base Data
    BusinessClient::class => BusinessClientPolicy::class,
];
```

The `view`method from this policy looks like this

```
public function view(User $user, BusinessClient $businessClient)
{
    return true;
}
```

To authorize my resource I called in the constructor of my apiResource Controller the `authorizeResource` method.

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
    $this->middleware('verified');
    $this->authorizeResource(BusinessClient::class, 'business_client');
}
```

My problem is that I alwas get a `401 Forbidden`response when I try to call the `show` method from my controller. What is going wrong with my code?

Comment: Your auth:api middleware could return this response. Are you authenticated using an API key (bearer token authentication)?